# NSIncludesSubdomains to support multiple subdomains

Tags: ios, info.plist, certificate-pinning

I am following [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y) to introduce NSPinnedDomains as the primary certificate pinning solution in our application.

We have a multiple environments to communicate to, and could have multiple subdomains, for example:

```
images.test-staging.backend.com
images.test-development.backend.com
image.backend.com
```

NSIncludesSubdomains [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsincludessubdomains) defines:

> it doesn’t apply to the subdomains advanced.math.example.com or ancient.history.example.com because those subdomains have two additional path components.

I understand, I can define domains as per environment

```
test-staging.backend.com
test-development.backend.com
backend.com
```

but if the backend would return an additional two subdomain

```
pretty.images.test-staging.backend.com
```

t will not be pinned.

I have tried to set domains as wildcards (`*.backend.com`), but it does not work.

Has somebody managed to find a solution for pinning against multiple subdomains?

Comment: any solution you found? Even i raised the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041864/nspinned-domains-seems-not-to-be-working-even-after-putting-incorrect-sha-key-fo

Comment: I am not using NSPinnedDomains in the end, but use my own implementation where i can check for hosts.

Comment: So there is no hope with NSPinnedDomains . Are you using any third party library ? Can you suggest one?

Comment: I could not figure out how to make it work on NSPinnedDomains.
Yes, i am using a third party, Alamofire, but that is a full blown networking SDK, maybe and overkill for what you need.